# Создание ссылки в статусе facebook (@Username)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Здравствуйте.

Проблема в том что бы создать ссылку(вида @username) на стене юзера/страницы, с помощью facebook api.

Искал в документации но ничего не нашел по этому поводу.

мой код:

```
$response = $facebook->api("/" . $data['pageId'] . "/feed", 'POST',
                    [
                        'message' => $messageContainer['message'],
                        'link' => 'https://example.com/reviews',
                        'name' => $messageContainer['subject'],
                        'description' => $messageContainer['description'],
                        'picture' => 'https://example.com/uploads/dealer/' . $messageContainer['logo'],
                    ]
                );
```

`$messageContainer['message'] = 'some text @username';`

Можете помочь или подсказать где искать?

Если хотите оставить ссылку на официальную документацию, то укажите пожалуйста конкретное место где я могу найти ответ, а не просто общую ссылку где она размещается.

Спасибо!

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? что бы @username было заменено на Имя пользователя?

Comment: @Bookin, собственно да и что бы подтягивалась информация о юзере/странице. 
Но я уже нашел решение, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

В документации написано что нужно в текст вставить id юзера или страницы вот так: `@[user_id]` или `@[page_id]`

Answer (score 1):

Могу показать Вам пример со своего сайта, себе сделаете по аналогу, тоже мучался два дня:

```
{foreach [

'vk-icon-lg' => "https://vk.com/share.php?url=$params.url&title=$params.title&description=$params.description&image=$params.image&noparse=true",

'fb-icon-lg' => "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=$params.url"

            ] as $item}
а также в индексном файле пишем "мета tags":

meta property="og:url" content="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST|escape}{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|escape}"/>

meta property="og:title" content="{$product->name|escape}"/>

meta property="og:description" content="{$product->meta_description|escape}" />

meta property="og:image" content="{$product->image->filename|resize:200:200}" />
```

Вам в массиве нужно оставить только url, остальное вынести с помощью meta tags в файл index.php
После этих манипуляций все работает хорошо.

Comment: спасибо, но это всё таки немного не то, мне не нужно шарить контент.
у меня задача состоит в том чтобы сделать ссылку(по типу как если бы мы набирали вручную @username), и что бы при наведении показывалась информация об этом юзернейме.
мета теги уже сделаны.
но всё равно спасибо!

Comment: @BogdanGudyma тогда будем ждать помощи от других знатоков, извините если что не так)